# Request WFS data using GeoServer's viewparams with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wfs, pyqgis-3

Using PyQGIS how can I request WFS data using GeoServer's viewparams request parameter?

I can use the viewparams request parameter to obtain the filtered WFS data I require via my web browser but not via PyQGIS.

The below returns the results I require via a browser and this appears to  be valid WFS GML
(Where `<LDS_API_KEY>` is the auth key generated by registered users via https://data.linz.govt.nz/. Please let me know if you can help and don't want to register and perhaps I can generate a temporary key to share)

```
https://data.linz.govt.nz/services;key=<LDS_API_KEY>/wfs?
SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&
REQUEST=GetFeature&
TYPENAMES=data.linz.govt.nz:layer-53353-changeset&
viewparams=from:2018-12-23T01:41:20.703998Z;to:2018-12-30T01:46:55.913620Z
```

via PyQGIS when trying to create a WFS vector layer with the same URL with the viewparams I get a invalid layer:

```
url = 'https://data.linz.govt.nz/services;key=<LINZ_API_KEY>/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=data.linz.govt.nz:layer-53353-changeset&viewparams=from:2018-12-23T01:41:20.703998Z;to:2018-12-30T01:46:55.913620Z'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(url, 'test', 'WFS')
layer.isValid()
>>> False
```

How can I request my WFS data with a viewparams filter?

Comment: Your PyQGIS code has `typename` but WFS 2 requires `typenames` which you have correct in your browser example

Comment: why not use a simple OGC filter rather than viewparams, then all would work as standard?

Comment: @nmtoken. Sorry I should have explained. GeoServer is backward compatible with typename. There appears to be a bug with QGIS, whereby wfs requests using typenames fails but typename succeeds.

Comment: @IanTurton This seems to be a custom implementation of GeoServer to handle change-sets. In the browser the viewparams returns what I require and this is why I had hoped to implement this approach with QGIS. I have attempted the CQL and OGC filtering (outside QGIS) with no success. The `to` and `from` properties are not part of the DescribeFeatureType and I guess? they need to be to filter on?. Using 'to' and 'from' raise the response `Illegal property name: from for feature type data.linz.govt.nz:layer-50647-changeset`